# Why can TPM2.0 sealing objects created under password-protected primary keys be loaded and used elsewhere without that password?

Tags: tpm

I have been investigating using the TPM2.0 for secure persistence of secrets using the [tpm2-tools](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools). It seems sealing objects are the way to go for this kind of thing.

I am hoping someone here might be able to better explain how sealing objects are related to the parent 'primary objects' that they are created and loaded under, especially when password auth values are involved. I've been a bit confused by some examples I've put together (below) that allow various operations without supplying the passwords I would have thought were required.

---

*(note: many of the examples below in practice require calls to `tpm2_flushcontext -t` to clear out space for intermediate object loading, but I have excluded them for brevity)*

As part of my evaluation I have learnt that sealing objects must always be created underneath some other 'primary object'/primary key that must be created first.

```
# make a new primary key
$ tpm2_createprimary -C o -c testprim.ctx
# make a new sealing object under this primary key
$ tpm2_create -u testseal.pub -r testseal.priv -i hunter2.txt -C testprim.ctx
```

These primary objects can optionally be created with password auth values on them. As you'd expect, trying to create a sealing object via a password-protected primary object without supplying its password doesn't work:

```
$ tpm2_createprimary -C o -p str:testpwd -c testprim-wauth.ctx
$ tpm2_create -u testseal-wpauth.pub -r testseal-wpauth.priv -i hunter2.txt -C testprim-wauth.ctx
WARNING:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Create.c:398:Esys_Create_Finish() Received TPM Error
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Create.c:134:Esys_Create() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x0000098e)
ERROR: Esys_Create(0x98E) - tpm:session(1):the authorization HMAC check failed and DA counter incremented
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_create
$ tpm2_create -u testseal-wpauth.pub -r testseal-wpauth.priv -i hunter2.txt -C testprim-wauth.ctx -P str:testpwd
# OK
```

What confuses me a bit is that loading and unsealing one of these created-under-the-auth-protected-primary-key objects works fine if the loading is done under a different *non-authed* primary key:

```
# no password required here
$ tpm2_load -C testprim.ctx -u testseal-wpauth.pub -r testseal-wpauth.priv -n testseal-loadedwnopauth.name -c testseal-loadedwnopauth.ctx
$ tpm2_unseal -c testseal-loadedwnopauth.ctx
hunter2
```

However, if loading under the auth-value-protected primary key, the password is required as expected for the loading...

```
# Try load without password
$ tpm2_load -C testprim-wauth.ctx -u testseal-wpauth.pub -r testseal-wpauth.priv -n testseal-loadedwpauth.name -c testseal-loadedwpauth.ctx
WARNING:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Load.c:324:Esys_Load_Finish() Received TPM Error
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Load.c:112:Esys_Load() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x0000098e)
ERROR: Eys_Load(0x98E) - tpm:session(1):the authorization HMAC check failed and DA counter incremented
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_load
# with password:
$ tpm2_load -C testprim-wauth.ctx -u testseal-wpauth.pub -r testseal-wpauth.priv -n testseal-loadedwpauth.name -c testseal-loadedwpauth.ctx -P str:testpwd
# OK
```

...but the unsealing still works without a password too.

```
$ tpm2_unseal -c testseal-loadedwpauth.ctx
hunter2
```

However, I'm assuming this is because the sealing object itself has no password on it. If the sealing object itself is given a password auth value (`-p` flag in `tpm2_create`) then it can never be unsealed without that password, which is expected behaviour, so that at least works fine.

I am just confused as to why things created under password-protected primary keys can still be seemingly used later without needing that password.

Is the password purely for the ability to create subsequent child objects under the primary key?

Am I missing something here?